# Command line based debugger for C# running on .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, powershell

**[Migrating from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548721/debug-c-sharp-from-the-command-line)**

**[Crossposting from SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548721/debug-c-sharp-from-the-command-line)**

**[Crossposting from Roslyn discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6203#discussion-4128667)**

**[Crossposing from .NET runtime discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/70440)**

I'm on a (possibly futile) quest to find a command line based debugger for C# applications running on the .NET 6 framework. Something similar to `jdb` for java or `pdb` for python. Here are the meagre resources I have found:

- [debugging c# in the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656864/debugging-c-sharp-in-the-command-line)
- [MDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791459/where-can-i-get-mdbg)
- [DebugExe flag for `devenv`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/debugexe-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)

The most promising by far would have been `MDbg`, but this looks very much outdated. [The page on the NuGet repository](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MDbg/) shows no version compatible with .NET 6.

I also made a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/uny9jn/command_line_based_debugger_for_csharp/) on reddit  but this unfortunately did not generate much discussion or answers.

Being able to hop into the debugger from the command line is a common feature among several languages, so I feel like it should exist for C#, however convoluted the process may be.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: Really command line or is a command-line-ish input sufficient. How about WinDbg?